# Capturing X,Y co-ordinates of pixel in Ti.paint titanium/android

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator, paint

Here i am facing a little problem , i am using Ti.paint module provided by the titanium appcelerator. The question is can I have all the x and y pixel co-ordinates on some event listener?I used this

```
    var paintView = Paint.createPaintView({
    top : 0,
    right : 0,
    bottom : 80,
    left : 0,
    strokeColor : '#0f0',
    strokeAlpha : 255,
    strokeWidth : 10,
    eraseMode : false
});

paintView.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {

    Ti.API.info('listener called ' + e.x + ',' + e.y);
});
```

But it do not capture all the X,Y co-ordinated it skips some of them.Painting slowly will capture almost all colored pixels co-ordinates but painting rapidly, skiping some pixel co-ordinated.Please help regarding this.

Ali

Answer (score 1):

The touch move event is throttled so that your code doesn't get overloaded.

If you absolutely need to get every point, then you need to cross over in to Java land and customize the paint module to your needs.

The module's source code is available here: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/paint/mobile/android